# Redirection issue htaccess or javascript?

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, url

Hi I need an advice on how to redirect a search result landing page. Here is the scenario let's say you went to our site www.sample.com then searched for cars you will get the result in the page below which is fine and what we want

```
http://www.sample.com/ili/all-categories/search?search_type=advanced&ap_search_keyword=cars,
```

now if I am on the homepage went to any of our category pages ex. services (category) or pets (category) and then make a search on those pages the url will now look like below. the search is different cause it is confined on that category.

```
http://www.sample.com/ili/services/search?search_type=advanced&ap_search_keyword=cars
http://www.sample.com/ili/pets/search?search_type=advanced&ap_search_keyword=cars
```

My question is how can I make the url change to `ili/all-categories/` instead of `ili/services` or `ili/pets` or `ili/(category)`
ex.

```
http://www.sample.com/ili/services/search?search_type=advanced&ap_search_keyword=cars
```

to

```
http://www.sample.com/ili/all-categories/search?search_type=advanced&ap_search_keyword=cars
```

Unfortunately our vendor is not able to do this and is not that flexible.
I do have control adding `js` and also `htaccess`.
our category pages url ex. `http://www.sample.com/ili/pets/search?` so I need the redirect to only happen when the last part of the url has `/search?search_type=advanced&ap_search_keyword=whatever`

Many thanks

Comment: I was thinking of using
`RewriteRule ^/(.*)/search?search_type=advanced&ap_search_keyword=(.*)$ /all-categories/search?search_type=advanced&ap_search_keyword=(.*)$ [L,R=301]` but not sure if I construct it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /ili

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \search_type=advanced&ap_search_keyword=(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(pets|services)
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /all-categories [R=301,L]
```

Comment: My category page is like this `http://www.sample.com/ili/pets/search?` so I need the redirect to only work if the url has `search_type=advanced&ap_search_keyword=whatever`

Comment: Try this @JamesTan

Comment: Thanks Lasitha will do